# R: Using an anonymous function to create dummy variables

Tags: r, anonymous-function, dummy-variable

Imagine you have a data set with a categorical variable and you want to turn it into dummy variables:

```
df<-data.frame(read.table(header = TRUE, text = 
"ID Mobile
1 Yes
2 No
3 Yes
4 Yes
5 No"))
```

I would normally do this as follows:

```
for(level in levels(df$Mobile)){
df[paste("Mobile", level, sep = "_")] <- ifelse(df$Mobile == level, 1,   0)
}
```

This works fine. However, now imagine you have many such categorical variables. Instead of copying and pasting these three lines of codes a number of times, you want to use an anonymous function. I tried it as follows:

```
Mediatable<-function(VARIABLE1, DUMMY1, INDICATOR1){
   for(level in levels(VARIABLE1)){
      df[paste(DUMMY1, level, sep = "_")] <- ifelse(VARIABLE1 == level, 1, 0)
   }
}
```

I would then trigger it as follows:

```
Mediatable(df$Mobile, "Mobile")
```

I tried it and nothing happened. Any idea what went wrong? I really like the idea of using an anonymous function to get this work across a number of categorical variables done. BTW, please ignore that I want to assign a specific name to my dummy variables by using paste. This does not matter here. Thanks!

Comment: Your function does not return a value. add `return(df)` outside of the for loop

Comment: @PierreLafortune, that is so true! Thanks so much for that! Post it as an answer and I will tick it right away! Thanks mate!

Comment: Try `model.matrix(~ Mobile + 0, df)`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck's answer is how I would do it.  But I also have to ask... why do you want to do this? Most times people go down this route they really don't need to and could just use factors instead.

Comment: @Dason! Thanks for the hint. Imagine Mobile was a factor. How would you then go about it? eager to learn more about!

Comment: @DomB That's why I asked what you're actually trying to do. Because I would just leave it as a factor.  For most things you don't need to explicitly create the dummy variables.

Comment: @DomB You still there?

Comment: @Dason, big apologies! I just saw this now. To answer your question, I work with categorical variables. I want to turn them into dummy variables (0/1). The idea is to then multiply these dummy variables with some sort of sampling weights. hence, I actually don't want to work with the the binary outcome values 0/1 but rather with 0/(1* sampling weight). I know there is some package for sampling weights that are much more elegant and perform much better. However, this approach also served some learning purposes. Does this make sense? Cheers, mate!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `return(df)` call in your function. Or use `dcast` from `reshape2` for another approach:

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df, ...~Mobile, length)
#   ID No Yes
# 1  1  0   1
# 2  2  1   0
# 3  3  0   1
# 4  4  0   1
# 5  5  1   0
```

With your function:

```
Mediatable<-function(VARIABLE1, DUMMY1, INDICATOR1){
        for(level in levels(VARIABLE1)){
                df[paste(DUMMY1, level, sep = "_")] <- ifelse(VARIABLE1 == level, 1, 0)
        }
        return(df)
}

newdf <- Mediatable(df$Mobile, "Mobile") 
newdf
#   ID Mobile Mobile_No Mobile_Yes
# 1  1    Yes         0          1
# 2  2     No         1          0
# 3  3    Yes         0          1
# 4  4    Yes         0          1
# 5  5     No         1          0
```

Comment: Maybe I was a bit too fast. Just a question for clarification. `return(df)` does print the output I hope to find in my data set. But it does not produce it permanently. What can I do that the anonymous function does indeed create the variables I need? Thanks